# Wordpress-blog with two languages - which plugin?

Tags: wordpress

I spent a couple of hours in the search of a solution to a two-languages-blog (site?). It seems that there are two general approaches: a single site which holds both languages; or two sites (thus WP installations) where each one holds a single language.

The solution for the latter one would be the Multisite Language Switcher.

But in principal, I'd prefer to work with a single site. Less hassle.

And I would like to use the same "New Post" page to enter the title and text for the languages - thus two title boxes, two text boxes. If I upload an image, I can insert it directly into each of the text boxes.

There, it seems the WPML is the way to go. Not sure about qTranslate. Tried it but only the title box was added.

Can you recommend anything else? Or am I thinking to narrowly? Thanks a lot for any hints or tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried out a couple of plugins. Finally spent many hour with multisite and domain mapping. When I got it working, I used the Multiple Language Switcher.... and like it a lot! Thanks for the hints!

Answer (score 1):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/polylang/ - easy to use and manage languages.

For each post you choose the language you'll need. You won't get to add both languages in the same post since it would result in the same url.

For images, you don't need to upload it twice, just choose it again from the media library.

Answer (score 1):

Not free, but WPML is probably the most advanced language plugin (hence the not free part). It will allow you to use a single install and choose the language based on directory or query string parameter. Overall fairly affordable.

http://wpml.org/